# Click on picture or link behind it

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, getelementbyid, getelementsbytagname

Hi I have macro which supposed to click on button on web page..problem is there is no ID behind just this code. Its intranet web page.

Begining of my code

```
    Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium

    IE.Navigate = "some website"

        While IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
          DoEvents
        Wend

IE.Visible = True

    IE.document.getElementById("CategoryCombo").Value = "78"
    IE.document.getElementById("CategoryCombo").FireEvent ("onchange")

'~~> wait until element is present on web page
    Do

        Set ieobj = Nothing

    On Error Resume Next

        Set ieobj = IE.document.getElementById("text1265")

        DoEvents

    Loop Until Not ieobj Is Nothing

'~~> search box
   IE.document.getElementById("text1265").Value = "some value"

'~~> button click example
   IE.document.getElementById("subBtn").Click
```

Part of website code

```
<a title="View document" href="javascript:FSResults_fsopenWindow('index.fsp?pn=DOLViewDocument&amp;d=78&amp;q=78-17158635-1&amp;o=78-17158635-1&amp;p=DOCUMENT_NAME#ensureVisible')" onclick="fsCancelEvent(event)"><img border="0" alt="View document" align="absmiddle" src="Images/DocTypes/PDF.gif"></a>
```

I tried

```
   IE.document.getElementByTitle("View document").FireEvent ("onclick")
```

I also tried

```
   IE.document.getElementByTagName("a").FireEvent ("onclick")
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I also tried
>
> `IE.document.getElementByTagName("a").FireEvent ("onclick")`

This should work for you, but you are missing something. You need to specify which `<a>` tag you are looking for, so `.getElementsByTagName("a")` turns into `.getElementsByTagName("a")(i)`, where `i` is the index of the tag you are looking for (you get the index by counting in order every `<a>` tag in the HTML, starting from 0).

The index is needed because `.getElementsByTagName("tagName")` returns an array, not a single value.

Comment: Hi, so I would loop through <a> until element is href? or similar?

Comment: You can also use a `For each` loop through that array, maybe until finding the given `.Title` property or the href, or you can just start counting all `<a>` tags to find the index of the one you need.

Comment: @FilipOndo there's an `<a>` tag for every single hyperlink in `IE.document` - the array return by `getElementsByTagName` contains every single one of them. You need to look at your page and see what's making *that link* the link you want to be clicking on.

Comment: @NicholasKemp `For Each` should be used for iterating collections. Iterating an array performs best with a `For` loop. See [VBA For vs For Each](http://analystcave.com/vba-for-loop-vs-for-each-loop/).

Comment: @MathieuGuindon thanks for the info, it's always good to learn something new.

Comment: thanks for inputs can I use this? `Dim elements As Object, element As Object, count As Long

count = 0
Set elements = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("a")(i)

For Each element In elements
    If element.Title = "View document" Then
        count = count + 1
        If count = 4 Then
        element.Click
        End If
    End If
Next`

Comment: That should work, just delete `(i)` from `getElementsByTagName` since you want to use the whole array in that case (Also, when you want a single value from the array you dont use `(i)` but an actual number).

Answer (score 1):

You could have used CSS selectors.

For example, an attribute selector

```
ie.document.querySelector("[title='View document']").Click
```

Or same thing to target href by its value

```
ie.document.querySelector("[href*=fsopenWindow]").Click
```

The last one looks for href containing `'fsopenWindow'`

Both of these avoid looping over collections of elements and use CSS so are faster.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I came up with this. Thank you for help Nicholas Kemp, your answer send me to right direction

```
Set elements = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("a")

For Each element In elements
    If Left(element, 33) = "javascript:FSResults_fsopenWindow" Then

    Debug.Print element
    IE.Navigate element

    End If

 Next
```